# Prove $\lim_{x\to2} (x^4 - 2x^3 + x + 3) = 5$ using Epsilon Delta

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove $\lim_{x\to2} (x^4 - 2x^3 + x + 3) = 5$ using Epsilon Delta

I am having difficulty finding the $\delta$ value.

Here is what I have done so far:

What I want to show:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \; such \; that \; 0<\mid x -2 \mid < \delta \implies \mid x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 2\mid < \epsilon $$

After a lot of manipulation, I was able to turn the equation to the following:

$$\mid x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 2\mid \; = \; \mid x-2 \mid \mid x-2 \mid \mid x + 1 \mid \mid x + 1 \mid + 3\mid x + 1 \mid \mid x - 2 \mid$$

I already know that $ \mid x -2 \mid < \delta$. I must find an upper bound for $\mid x + 1 \mid$.

$$\mid x + 1 \mid = \mid x + 1 -3 + 3 \mid \; \le \; \mid x - 2 \mid + 3 $$
Choose $\delta = 1$, then
$$\mid x - 2 \mid < 1 \implies \mid x -2 \mid + 3 < 4$$
Therefore $\mid x + 1 \mid < 4$

This means:
$$\mid x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 2\mid < (\delta)(\delta)(4)(4) + 3(\delta)(4) = 16\delta^2 + 12\delta = \epsilon$$

This is where I get stuck. How do I transform $16\delta^2 + 12\delta = \epsilon$ into solving for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

I am not sure if I am over thinking the whole question or if the above is even remotely correct. Please let me know any mistakes that I have made.

Comment: Your life gets easier if you first write the polynomial as a sum of powers of $x-2$. Otherwise, the equation for $\delta$ that you got can be solved using the *quadratic formula*, the one with the discriminant and all of that.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the quadratic formula *works*, but this is really not the best way of going about this problem I think. It greatly over complicates an otherwise very simple proof, as given in my answer (which actually uses Pp..'s suggestion by the way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very **easy** and brief way to do it:

Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $|(x^4-2x^3+x+3)-5|<\epsilon$.

Now, 
$$|(x^4-2x^2+x+3)-5|=|(x-2)(x^3+1)|.
$$ If $|x-2|<1$, that is, $1<x<3$, then $x^3+1<3^3+1=28$, and so 
$$
|(x^4-2x^3+x+3)-5|=|x-2|(x^3+1)<28|x-2|.
$$ So if we take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{28}\right\}$, then 
$$
0<|x-2|<\delta\to|(x^4-2x^2+x+3)-5|=|(x-2)|(x^3+1)<\frac{\epsilon}{28}\cdot 28=\epsilon.
$$ Thus, by the definition of a limit, $\lim_{x\to 2}(x^4-2x^3+x+3)=5$.

Comment: This makes things so simple! I originally had $|(x-2)(x^3+1)|$, but I went ahead and turned it to the ugly mess I have above! :) Thank you!

Comment: @ashimashi You're welcome! I thought my proof was definitely the *cleanest* approach. Glad it makes sense now :)

Comment: I have one other question. This won't affect the final answer, but shouldn't the $(x^3 + 1)$ be $|x^3 + 1|$?

Comment: Hint: how did we choose $\delta$? That should answer your question :) If it doesn't, I'd suggest rereading the section of whatever text you're using (or some other resource) about epsilon-delta proofs. Khan Academy has some good stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I explained it poorly. You stated: $|(x^4−2x^3+x+3)−5|=|x−2|(x^3+1)$. My question is, doesn't the left side equal to $|x−2||x^3+1|$ instead of $|x−2|(x^3+1)$?

Comment: My hint was meant to address that :) It has to do with how we choose $\delta$.

Comment: Oh, $\delta > 0$. That's what you meant. Alrighty, thanks!

Comment: @ashimashi Does it all make sense now? I hope so! Good luck.

Comment: @ashimashi The reason why $|x^3+1|=(x^3+1)$ is not $\delta>0$. It is rather the $|x-2|<1$. You see, $x^3+1\geq0$ for $x\geq-1$. If we had $x<-1$ then $|x-2|>3$.

Comment: As Pp.. pointed out, it is not that $\delta>0$. It is the *choice* of $\delta$ that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have done all this work so far, just use the quadratic formula to complete the argument. The two roots are $\frac{ -12 \pm \sqrt{(-12)^2 + 4(16)(\epsilon)}}{2(16)}$. Then set

$$\delta = \min\left\{1,\frac{-12 +\sqrt{144 +64\epsilon}}{32}\right\}$$

The equation always has real roots. I had to take the minimum of $1$ and the root since you had already made the assumption $\delta<1$ in your computations.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be: $\delta = min(1,\frac{-12 +\sqrt{144 +64\epsilon}}{32})$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you haven't assumed that $\delta<1$ at some point in the proof, you won't need it in this case. The choice of such a specific $\delta$ above is because when you plug it into your polynomial, you get exactly $\epsilon$, so no further restrictions are needed.

Comment: But I had assigned $\delta = 1$ to create an upper bound for $\mid x - 2 \mid < 1 $. If I had not done that, I never would have gotten to that quadratic formula. Does that not count?

Comment: Yes this counts. I read through the post quickly, my apologies. You should however take $\delta<1$ not $\delta=1$. By choosing $1$ you have made a choice for $\delta$ which you don't want to do until the end. I will change my post to address your comment.

Answer (score 3):

It can be settled without resorting to the "quadratic formula".

$16\delta^2+12\delta = 4\delta(4\delta+3)$. If you choose $\delta < 1$, then your job is a bit easier, since then $4\delta+3 < 7$, and $4\delta(4\delta+3) < 7\cdot 4\delta = 28\delta$. Next you want that $28\delta < \epsilon $, thus $\delta < \dfrac{\epsilon}{28}$. Now you have an idea of how to select $\delta$. You can take $\delta = \text{min}(1,\frac{\epsilon}{28})$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\text{Write the polynomial as a sum of powers of $x-2$.}$$

$$x^4-2x^3+x+3=(x-2)^4+6(x-2)^3+12(x-2)^2+9(x-2)+5$$

> The most efficient way to do this is to apply [Ruffini-Horner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Examples) repeatedly with the polynomial with the value $x=2$.

Then $$|x^4-2x^3+x+3-5|=|(x-2)^4+6(x-2)^3+12(x-2)^2+9(x-2)|\leq(1+6+12+9)|x-2|$$

when $|x-2|<1$. So, you only need to put $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/(1+6+12+9)).$

Comment: I don't understand, If I no longer have the $\mid x + 1\mid$, why would I need to assign an upper bound ($|x-2|<1$)? I already know that $\mid x - 2 \mid < \delta$. Wouldn't it mean that: $\mid x^4-3x^3+x+3-5 \mid \le 28\delta = \epsilon \implies \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{28}$?

Comment: @ashimashi What if te $\epsilon$ they gave you is $\epsilon=28\cdot 5052352$?

Comment: Never mind, I understand why now. I  DON'T understand why your answer got downvoted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ashimashi Although it is not very important, why was it?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo, I meant I don't understand why your answer got downvoted. Sorry about that.